# int to NSUINteger conversion issue

Tags: ios, nsuinteger

i have a situation like this. i want to remove some object in a particular index in a mutable array. so i have a method for do that by passing the index. but it takes NSUInteger as a parameter. but i got an integer value as the index. when i call my method, the parameter value is null.. below is my code

```
for (int x=0; x<tempAry.count; x++) {

                NSArray* temp = [tempAry objectAtIndex:x];

                NSString* appoinment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[temp valueForKey:@"AppointmentId"]];

                if ([appoinment isEqualToString:appoinmentID_for_rejct]) {

                    //attention here
                     NSUInteger* index = (NSUInteger*)x;
                    [TableViewController removeIndexfromDuplicate:index];

                }
            }
```

here the index got null..how can i fix this.? the index should not be null.. because x is not a null value..please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did see here (Converted an integer to pointer value, is there any specific reason to do ???):

```
//attention here
NSUInteger* index = (NSUInteger*)x;
[TableViewController removeIndexfromDuplicate:index];
```

It should be like this:

```
NSUInteger index = x;
[TableViewController removeIndexfromDuplicate:index];
```

Or simply use `x` as `[TableViewController removeIndexfromDuplicate:x];`

**Side Note: Follow good naming convention. `TableViewController` looks like a class!!!*

Comment: About side note : yes it is a class @Anoop . removeIndexfromDuplicate:x is a private method which is working like setter..